# Determine whether series is divergent or convergent

Tags: calculus

$$\sum_{n = 3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(\ln n)^2}$$

I used Integral Test and I am up to $$\frac{-1}{\ln x}$$ Do I need to plug in $0$ and $t$ to find out if it is divergent or convergent?

Comment: The integral test reduces the convergence of certain series to the convergence of related improper integrals. Are you asking about how improper integrals are evaluated?

Comment: The integral used here is $$\int_3^\infty \frac{1}{x\log^2(x)}\,dx=\frac{1}{\log(3)}<\infty$$

Comment: I was confused on what I needed to do after getting it to $\frac{1}{lnx}$ I wasn't sure how getting it in the form I had would determine if it was divergent or convergent.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test

Comment: If you read French or Spanish, you'll find all you have to know about *Bertrand's series* on [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9rie_de_Bertrand).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need plug in $0$ and $t$ to find out whether it converges. Instead, you need to plug in $3$ which is the lower limit of the summation and the $\infty$ which is the upper limit of the summation in order to ascertain whether it diverges.

By [Integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence):
$$\sum_{n = 3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(lnn)^2} < \frac{1}{3(ln3)^2}+\int_{3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x(lnx)^2}dx$$

$$\int \frac{1}{x(lnx)^2}dx = -\frac{1}{lnx}+C$$.

So When $x \to \infty$, $\ln{x} \to \infty$, $\frac{1}{\ln x} \to 0$.
When $x = 3$,  $-\frac{1}{lnx} = -\frac{1}{\ln 3}$

Then $$\sum_{n = 3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(lnn)^2} < \frac{1}{3(ln3)^2}+[-\frac{1}{lnx}]_3^{\infty} = \frac{1}{3(ln3)^2}+\frac{1}{\ln 3}$$.

Therefore the series converges.

Comment: did you determine it was convergent by using the direct comparison test?

Comment: @Bazfred Nope. I use the integral test as you recommended in the problem.

Comment: @Bazfred If you need the result of direct comparison test, you can see Jack's comment below the question. (i.e. Cauchy Condensation Test)